# moving postgresql main folder out of /var/lib/postgresql/9.4

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have a debian installed server, where I have used `apt` to install pgsql9.4 a few months ago. Now, after a month, I see that the folder totals to 19GB:

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main
```

is taking up all my space of `rootfs` (19GB). Agreed, I am writing some heavy UTf-8 stuff onto the instance.

It is probably daft to ask, but, is there a way I can `move` this folder/installation in postgres to another disk? and still not affect my db? Can this be even done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can.

1. Stop the PostgreSQL server.

   `/etc/init.d/postgresql stop`
2. Move the data directory somewhere else.

   `mv /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main /storage/ssd/`
3. Make a symlink pointing to the new location.

   `ln -s /storage/ssd/main /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main`
4. Start the PostgreSQL server.

   `/etc/init.d/postgresql start`

Comment: Wow.. that was simple.. I thought it would be complicated! Thanks so much.. Works like a charm.. :) Accepted your answer.